# Dynamic LINQ (Select clause) keyword issue:

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have been using an application I have made to distribute around my company which gives an average non-techie user(accountant, marketing type, mgmt) the ability to query any size DB with fast and friendly results. It uses the Dynamic.cs class to

1. Select all tables in a given DB
2. Select some filtered columns/fields in any Table
3. At runtime it figures out what the type is and then chooses which operators the user
   can enter to aid their query
4. It gives the ability to only display the fields the user selects.
5. and Finally it gives the ability to Order and Group By

People, especially my superiors, LOVE it as it is incredibly useful. I can put this application on any DB and in 5 minutes they are able to query and export to Excel Worksheets in seconds.

Now, here is my issue, when I generate my select clause, if I have the field named "Object" I get a parse error from Dynamic.cs "Expecting a "(" or a "." - I am quite sure this is a keyword issue, and when the Parser hits the word Object it gets confused.**

One of my developers thinks, oh just write a partial class to get around the issue, but I think this is a serious enough bug, that I would like to fix the Dynamic.cs class -

Can anyone help me on this???  I have researched but have not found anything to point me in the right direction. I am pretty sure I could fix this but time is not on my side

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are making a syntax error i guess, secondly even if you remove that syntax error it wont work because you are trying to create a dynamic select statement I guess, which is not as simple as you guess.

Dynamic linq library or regular expression can help you.